# ISO date comparison in native javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have muddling with date comparison in native javascript or jquery, can anybody point me out how i can quickly do the comparison with today's date in ISO-8601 format

Comment: Maybe Moment.js has helpful functions for this.

Comment: I included moment.js as i could not find an effective way of doing it and tried putting moment() in console and it says it is undefined? Any ideas?

Comment: Thank for you not asking for a moment.js solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This

```
var d1 = new Date('2013-08-02T10:09:08Z'), // 10:09 to
    d2 = new Date('2013-08-02T10:20:08Z'); // 10:20 is 11 mins
//Get the difference

var diff = d2 - d1;
//Format this as desired.

if (diff > 60e3) console.log(
    Math.floor(diff / 60e3), 'minutes ago'
);
else console.log(
    Math.floor(diff / 1e3), 'seconds ago'
);
// 11 minutes ago
```

OR

```
alert((dateFromISO8601("2013-08-02T10:20:08Z") - dateFromISO8601("2013-08-02T10:09:08Z")) / 60000); //Response in Milisecnds so Divide by 60000 For Minutes

function dateFromISO8601(isostr) {
    var parts = isostr.match(/\d+/g);
    return new Date(parts[0], parts[1] - 1, parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5]);
}
```

Comment: I actually did not tried this despite of seeing this. This is correct.

Comment: @RobG, Now you can check it in any browser :) ;)

Comment: @RobG, plz check the diff.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do string comparison on two valid `ISO8601` strings (i.e. `new Date().toISOString()`) and it'll work

```
"2021-07-02T21:50:01.926Z" > "2021-07-04T21:49:56.863Z" // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two dates by using new Date() method in javascript. Here's is the code to compare two dates.

```
var date1 = "28/08/2008";
var date2 = "12/02/2014";

if(new Date(date1) > new Date(date2)){
   alert("Date 1 is greater then Date 2");
}else{
   alert("Date 2 is greater than Date 1");
}
```

Comment: 2014-08-05T01:28:48.909Z

Comment: Do not allow the Date object to parse strings, it's notoriously inconsistent across browsers (even when using the single format specified by [*ECMA-262 ed 5*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)). Parse the strings manually (e.g. my browser things 12/02/2014 is 2 December, 2014 and 28/08/2014 is invalid).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the Date constructor to parse strings as the result is inconsistent across browsers. Manually parse the strings.

If you have an ISO 8601 format like 2014-08-05T01:28:48.909Z it's very easy to parse:

```
// Given an ISO 8601 string, return a date object
function parseISO(s) {
  s = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(s[0],--s[1],s[2],s[3],s[4],s[5],s[6]));
}
```

Now you can compare the dates like:

```
var d0 = '2014-02-06T23:45:15.987Z';
var d1 = '2014-02-06T23:48:15.987Z';

if (parseISO(d0) < parseISO(d1)) {
  // d0 is before d1
}
```